# How to make a fixed positioned div use the rest width of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have **2 columns in a container** (whose width dynamically changes in our situation). **The left-column (green) has always a fix width** of i.e. 100px, and flows with the document as usual. **The right column (blue) has a position: fixed**, because i have a JS code, which sets the top&bottom positions of this right column dependent on the scroll position.

I want that my **fixed positioned right column does not expand its parent on the X axis, but just use the space left from the left-column**. Is it possible?

Now i have width:inherit, which actually makes the whole right-column having the same width as its parent. But i have to substract the width of the left-column from this width, so that the right-column does not expand the container.

Here is a fiddle for a simplified version of my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/gj4a5hde/

[image]

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1400px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.left-column {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.right-column {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 110px; /* always fix, since the width of the left-column does not change */
  height: 200px;
  width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column"></div>
  <div class="right-column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use position: fixed for right column ?

Comment: more or less yes..  you can see a similar behaviour on this site: https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=koch&l&advn=1602870993123190&vjk=8113fc2d158182a9  where the right column also has a fixed positioning because of the scroll position dependency. The difference is, in our case the width of the right column can be changed, when the container goes wider or narrower.

Comment: I think using css-flex or css-grid (without position: fixed) this is achievable, if you are able to change that javascript to set margin-top instead of top.

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent `.container` to have `transform: translate(0,0)`. This will make the fixed element "fixed" to the parent instead of the viewport. Then use `calc(100% - 110px)` to set the width of your fixed element. That will take the `margin` into account and remove it from the overall width of the fixed element.

You will need to adjust the `top` value to what you want.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1400px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transform: translate(0,0);
}

.left-column {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.right-column {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 110px; /* always fix, since the width of the left-column does not change */
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 110px);
  max-width: inherit;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column"></div>
  <div class="right-column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer..  the idea is really nice but it unfortunately does not work in my case. Vertically the right column should be relative to viewport, since all the top&bottom calculations with JS cannot be changed..

Comment: @akcasoy ah, that wasn't part of your original question. If you are using JS to set the top and bottom, why not use it to set the height of the `right-column` as well? How much control do you have over the JS?

Comment: please look at this site: https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=koch&l&advn=1602870993123190&vjk=8113fc2d158182a9 they have a similar "right-column-structure". We need to set the top&bottom relative to viewport. The only difference is, in our case the width of the right column can be changed, when the parent container goes wider or narrower.